# use Two-dimensional list in spinner

Tags: android

i have a list :

```
[{    
    "catid": 1,
    "title": "windows" 
    },
    {
    "catid": 2,
    "title": "Android",
    }
]
```

i want show list titles in spinner.
when user select a title, variable (int)selected_item equals corresponding catid.
for example when user select title "Android" from spinner , (int)selected_item = 2;

```
   public void setupcatspinner(ArrayList<String> titles,ArrayList<Integer> catids){

    final Spinner s1 =  findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap=new ArrayAdapter<>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titles);
    adap.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adap);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           // (int)selected_item = ???
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: To answer the question properly it is necessary to know what `titles` is.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)

Therefore `selected_item = titles.get(position).get(0)`, assuming 0 is the index of `catid` the the two dimensional list `titles`.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain two different list one for ids and other for titles. Set `OnItemSelectedListener` to spinner and you will get the selected item position , get the corresponding id from catId list.
Check the code below,

```
    // List containing all category ids
    ArrayList<String> catIdList = new ArrayList<>();
    // List containing all titles
    ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Store the data in respective lists
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        if(jsonObject.has("catid")){
            catIdList.add(jsonObject.getString("catid"));
        }
        if(jsonObject.has("title")){
            titleList.add(jsonObject.getString("title"));
        }
    }
```

You can pass `titleList` to `SpinnerAdapter`.

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String catId = catIdList.get(position);
            String title = titleList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: what is "data" in :  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data)  ?

Comment: Data is your json array.. `[{ "catid": 1, "title": "windows" }, { "catid": 2, "title": "Android", } ]`